# How to get Api-User and request-uri from HttpHeaders

Tags: java, spring-mvc, header, http-headers, httprequest

In my Controller I am using

```
   "@Context HttpHeaders headers"
```

I created a  Multi-ValuedMap and stored all the HttpHeader parameters in that using

```
   MultivaluedMap<String, String> headersMap = headers.getRequestHeaders();
```

When I looked the documentation for HttpHeaders I couldn't find requestUri and Api-User. How can I get the request-uri and Api-User from this headersMap.

Answer (score 0):

Several packages have MultivaluedMap these days, like this one.

You should be able to call:

```
String apiUser = headersMap.getFirst("Api-User");
String uri = headersMap.getFirst("request-uri");
```